# Trouble setting program flow to correctly run a function

Tags: java, javafx

I have a class tasks, which handles multiple tasks using a menu layout, class tasks check the application flow by setting up the stage, with the menu scene to list all individual task. I want to run some task from the available list using there own classes, something like this:

**Tasks.java:**

```java
    package tasks;
    
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    
    public class Tasks extends Application
    {
        private Stage window;
        private Scene menuScene;
        private Task1 task1;
    
        public Tasks()
        {
            this.window=null;
            this.menuScene=null;
            this.task1=null;
        }
    
        private void setMenu()
        {
            VBox menu=new VBox();
    
            Button newTask1Button=new Button("New Task 1");
            newTask1Button.setOnAction(clickEvent -> this.startNewTask1());
            menu.getChildren().add(newTask1Button);
    
            //More buttons
    
            this.menuScene=new Scene(menu,400,600);
        
            this.window.setScene(this.menuScene);
        }
    
        private void startNewTask1()
        {
            this.task1=new Task1(this.window);
            this.launchTask1();
        }
    
        private void launchTask1()
        {
            if(this.task1!=null)
            {
                int task1State=1;
                //while(task1State==1) //To re-run for pause state
                //{
                    task1State=this.task1.runTask1();
                    System.out.println("Task1 is in state "+task1State); //In no way part of program, just for debugging. Always give state=-1
                    //If 1-Paused, then display pause Menu for task1, by calling this.task1.paused(); and then again based on user input re-run runTask1
                    //If 0-Exit, then change the scene back to menuScene and quit the function
                //}
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage)
        {
            this.window=primaryStage;
            this.window.setTitle("Tasks");
    
            this.setMenu();
    
            this.window.show();
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Application.launch(args);
        }
    }
```

**Task1.java:**

```java
    package tasks;
    
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    
    class Task1
    {
        private Stage window;
        private Scene task1Scene;
        private boolean intialised;
    
        private int state;
    
        public Task1()
        {
        }
        public Task1(Stage _window)
        {
            this.window=_window;
            this.task1Scene=null; //Will be set later
            this.intialised=false;
            this.state=-1;
        }
    
        private Scene createScene()
        {
            //Creates some GUI to interact
            
            //Buttons in End, to control exit
            HBox menu=new HBox();
    
            Button pauseButton=new Button("Pause");
            pauseButton.setOnAction(clickEvent -> this.state=1);
            menu.getChildren().add(pauseButton);
            
            Button exitButton=new Button("Exit");
            exitButton.setOnAction(clickEvent -> this.state=0);
            menu.getChildren().add(exitButton);
    
            Scene scene=new Scene(menu,400,600);
    
            return scene;
        }
    
        private void setupControls()
        {
            //To assign event handlers to interact with GUI
        }
    
        public int runTask1()
        {
            if(!this.intialised)
                this.task1Scene=this.createScene();
            this.window.setScene(this.task1Scene);
    
            this.setupControls();

            //while(this.state==-1);
        
            return this.state;
        }
    }
```

The problem with this I face is, function `runTask1()` is always instantly returning, even though operation assigned using event handlers for Task1 are still running and no event for exit has been generated.

I tried to solve this by setting an instance variable named state and setting it to -1, and putting a while loop till this state variable is not modified. But that completely stops the GUI.

I realised its reason later by Googling, but couldn't determine which way to solve this.

At places, it was suggested to use Threads (not sure how, I don't want multiple processes running in the program) and at places, it was also suggested to set another Event Handler (but, they were running the different process in the `start()` function (inherited from Application) itself and it was more of transferring the flow rather than returning backwards).

How should I code to keep running only `runTask1()` till it is not finished, and return to `launchTask1()` sequentially?

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: @kleopatra Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infinite `while` loop in method `runTask1()` in class `Task1` is freezing the [JavaFX application thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm). Just remove it.

Basically your `Task1` class is another `Scene` so when you click on button `newTask1Button` in class `Tasks` you simply want to set a new `Scene`.

Here is class `Task1` with the required change.

```java
package tasks;

import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class Task1 {
    private Stage window;
    private Scene task1Scene;
    private boolean intialised;

    private int state;

    public Task1() {
    }

    public Task1(Stage _window) {
        this.window = _window;
        this.task1Scene = null; // Will be set later
        this.intialised = false;
        this.state = -1;
    }

    private Scene createScene() {
        // Creates some GUI to interact

        // Buttons in End, to control exit
        HBox menu = new HBox();

        Button pauseButton = new Button("Pause");
        pauseButton.setOnAction(clickEvent -> this.state = 1);
        menu.getChildren().add(pauseButton);

        Button exitButton = new Button("Exit");
        exitButton.setOnAction(clickEvent -> this.state = 0);
        menu.getChildren().add(exitButton);

        Scene scene = new Scene(menu, 400, 600);

        return scene;
    }

    private void setupControls() {
        // To assign event handlers to interact with GUI
    }

    public int runTask1() {
        if (!this.intialised)
            this.task1Scene = this.createScene();
        this.window.setScene(this.task1Scene);

        this.setupControls();

//        while (this.state == -1)
//            ;

        return this.state;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I simply commented out the `while` loop. The JavaFX application thread contains a loop that waits for user actions to occur such as moving the mouse or typing a key on the keyboard. You don't have to handle that in your code.

### EDIT

As a result of the typo in the code in your question, that you mentioned in your comment to my answer and that you corrected in your question in a subsequent edit, I am editing my answer.

The way a JavaFX application works is that it reacts to user actions. You want class `Tasks` to be notified when the "state", in class `Task1`, is changed and the "state" is changed when the user clicks on either `pauseButton` or `exitButton` in class `Task1`. According to the code you posted, you could callback to class `Tasks` from the event handler of `pauseButton`.

Class `Task1`.
(Note comment *CHANGE HERE* and extra parameter in constructor.)

```java
package tasks;

import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class Task1 {
    private Tasks tasks;
    private Stage window;
    private Scene task1Scene;
    private boolean intialised;

    private int state;

    public Task1(Stage _window, Tasks tasks) {
        this.tasks = tasks;
        this.window = _window;
        this.task1Scene = null; // Will be set later
        this.intialised = false;
        this.state = -1;
    }

    private Scene createScene() {
        HBox menu = new HBox();
        Button pauseButton = new Button("Pause");
        pauseButton.setOnAction(clickEvent -> tasks.setState(this.state = 1)); // CHANGE HERE
        menu.getChildren().add(pauseButton);
        Button exitButton = new Button("Exit");
        exitButton.setOnAction(clickEvent -> this.state = 0);
        menu.getChildren().add(exitButton);
        Scene scene = new Scene(menu, 400, 600);
        return scene;
    }

    private void setupControls() {
        // To assign event handlers to interact with GUI
    }

    public int runTask1() {
        if (!this.intialised) {
            this.task1Scene = this.createScene();
        }
        this.window.setScene(this.task1Scene);
        this.setupControls();
        return this.state;
    }
}
```

---

Class `Tasks`
(Added method `setState(int)`.)

```java
package tasks;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class Tasks extends Application {
    private Stage window;
    private Scene menuScene;
    private Task1 task1;

    public Tasks() {
        this.window = null;
        this.menuScene = null;
        this.task1 = null;
    }

    private void setMenu() {
        VBox menu = new VBox();
        Button newTask1Button = new Button("New Task 1");
        newTask1Button.setOnAction(clickEvent -> this.startNewTask1());
        menu.getChildren().add(newTask1Button);
        this.menuScene = new Scene(menu, 400, 600);
        this.window.setScene(this.menuScene);
    }

    private void startNewTask1() {
        this.task1 = new Task1(this.window, this);
        this.launchTask1();
    }

    private void launchTask1() {
        if (this.task1 != null) {
            this.task1.runTask1();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.window = primaryStage;
        this.window.setTitle("Tasks");
        this.setMenu();
        this.window.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    public void setState(int task1State) {
        System.out.println("Task1 is in state " + task1State); // In no way part of program,
                                                               // just for debugging.
    }
}
```

Comment: I have realised that issue earlier only(apology for that, I forgot to comment it in code). The function is returning early without being staying on it until a valid return initiated. I want to return specific codes from the functions {0,1} based on user choice, but it is returning default value -1.

Comment: Thanks for the idea of creating a binary association, l better should call back to tasks, rather than trying to return.